# Can example@yahoo.co.uk connect with example2@yahoo.com?

Tags: yahoo-mail

I have a yahoo.co.uk account and my friend has a yahoo.com account. Can we still connect via Yahoo! like both had the same domain and chat?

Comment: Yes, you can. Personal experience from the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they both belong to yahoo and can be used for chatting. They are just different domain names like  while .co.uk is for UK and .com is just general. But its **still yahoo**, so u DEFINITELY can chat between them.

Answer (score -1):

I am .com and have trouble with people contacting me as it automatically goes to co.uk upon reply, I don't see or receive the reply and they get told there's no such email.